# How to export mysql database to excel with extra column

Tags: php, mysql, excel

i need to export my database to excel. But i have two tabel (users,users document) i need to mix them when exporting and add extra column dynamicly? is there any way

I have watched many videos but those are single database and can't add column

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SELECT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) outfile which will write the output into the file and in this case you want to write into CSV. Write down your JOIN queries with some tables, after that you can send the result into the file. You must define your column in the queries, otherwise if you want to have a dynamic column, you must write a function to accommodate that.